# При наводе на блок останавливать функцию в которой есть setTimeout, а при выходе мышки из блока, заново запускать функцию

Tags: javascript, css

Есть блок, в котором есть 5 блоков и 5 картинок. В каждом блоке есть анимация (линия прогресса) которая заполняется до 100%. Сразу активный блок - первый. Когда у первого блока заполняется шкала прогресса, активный блок становится второй и меняется картинка, а так же запускается шкала прогресса у второго блока. После второго блока, по такой же технологии запускается третий блок, потом четвертый и потом пятый, а после пятого снова первый и так по кругу. Шкала прогресса сделана через анимацию CSS, а активность блоков и смена картинок через JS (функция активности).
Но так же нужно, чтобы при новоде на блок, функция активности останавливалась и активный становился тот блок, на который я навел мышкой, а так же запускалась другая анимация CSS (шкала прогресса доходила до 100% и все, не нужно чтобы на другой блок переходило), но когда мышь уберу с этого блока, нужно чтобы заново началась та функция активности и аниамация CSS с первого блока. Очень надеюсь что все понятно написал, но если нет, то задавайте вопросы, на все отвечу. И да, код JS не очень хороший, но я еще только учусь и пишу как умею

```js
const imgHover = () => {
    const productImg = document.querySelectorAll('.product-img'); //блоки с картинкой
    const productImg1 = document.querySelector('.product-img_1');
    const productImg2 = document.querySelector('.product-img_2');
    const productImg3 = document.querySelector('.product-img_3');
    const productImg4 = document.querySelector('.product-img_4');
    const productImg5 = document.querySelector('.product-img_5');
    const itemNum = document.querySelectorAll('.product__list_item'); // все блоки под одним классом
    const productListItemTextProgressGrad = document.querySelectorAll('.product__list_item_text_progress_grad'); // шкала прогресса
    const itemNum1 = document.querySelector('.item-num-1'); //блоки на которые нужно наводить по отдельности
    const itemNum2 = document.querySelector('.item-num-2');
    const itemNum3 = document.querySelector('.item-num-3');
    const itemNum4 = document.querySelector('.item-num-4');
    const itemNum5 = document.querySelector('.item-num-5');
  
    //функция которая делает активнсть блоков при наводе на них и убирает прошлую анимацию и подставляет новую
    function prov(one, two, three) {
        productListItemTextProgressGrad.forEach((item, ind) => {
            item.style.animation = "none";
            if(ind == one) {
                item.style.animation = "product_progress_one ease-out 25s";
            }
        });
        itemNum.forEach(item => {
            item.classList.remove('active');
        })
        productImg.forEach(el => {
            el.classList.remove('active');
        })
        two.classList.add('active');
        three.classList.add('active');
    }
    
        // функция которая запускает автоматически смену активности при заполнении шкалы
        const framesImg = () => {
        productListItemTextProgressGrad.forEach((item, ind) => {
            item.style.animation = "product_progress ease-out 25s";
        });
        itemNum5.classList.remove('active');
        itemNum1.classList.add('active');
        productImg5.classList.remove('active');
        productImg1.classList.add('active');
        setInterval(() => {
            itemNum5.classList.remove('active');
            itemNum1.classList.add('active');
            productImg5.classList.remove('active');
            productImg1.classList.add('active');
        }, 25000);
        setTimeout(() => {
            itemNum1.classList.remove('active');
            itemNum2.classList.add('active');
            productImg1.classList.remove('active');
            productImg2.classList.add('active');
            setInterval(() => {
                itemNum1.classList.remove('active');
                itemNum2.classList.add('active');
                productImg1.classList.remove('active');
                productImg2.classList.add('active');
            }, 25000);
        }, 5000);
        setTimeout(() => {
            itemNum2.classList.remove('active');
            itemNum3.classList.add('active');
            productImg2.classList.remove('active');
            productImg3.classList.add('active');
            setInterval(() => {
                itemNum2.classList.remove('active');
                itemNum3.classList.add('active');
                productImg2.classList.remove('active');
                productImg3.classList.add('active');
            }, 25000);
        }, 10000);
        setTimeout(() => {
            itemNum3.classList.remove('active');
            itemNum4.classList.add('active');
            productImg3.classList.remove('active');
            productImg4.classList.add('active');
            setInterval(() => {
                itemNum3.classList.remove('active');
                itemNum4.classList.add('active');
                productImg3.classList.remove('active');
                productImg4.classList.add('active');
            }, 25000);
        }, 15000);
        setTimeout(() => {
            itemNum4.classList.remove('active');
            itemNum5.classList.add('active');
            productImg4.classList.remove('active');
            productImg5.classList.add('active');
            setInterval(() => {
                itemNum4.classList.remove('active');
                itemNum5.classList.add('active');
                productImg4.classList.remove('active');
                productImg5.classList.add('active');
            }, 25000);
        }, 20000);
        
    }
    framesImg();
    
    // наведение на каждый блок 
    itemNum.forEach(elem => {
        elem.addEventListener('mouseover', (e) => {

            if(e.target.classList.contains('product__list_item_one')) {
                prov(0, productImg1, itemNum1);
            } else if (e.target.classList.contains('product__list_item_two')) {
                prov(1, productImg2, itemNum2);
            } else if (e.target.classList.contains('product__list_item_three')) {
                prov(2, productImg3, itemNum3);
            } else if (e.target.classList.contains('product__list_item_four')) {
                prov(3, productImg4, itemNum4);
            } else if (e.target.classList.contains('product__list_item_five')) {
                prov(4, productImg5, itemNum5);
            }
       
        });
    });
}
imgHover()
```

```css
.product__list {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}

.product__list_wrapper {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}

.product__list_wrapper-hidden {
  position: relative;
  display: none;
}

.product__list_column-1 {
  max-width: 581px;
}

.product__list_column-2 {
  margin-left: 100px;
  max-width: 500px;
}

.product__list_column-text-2 {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
  max-width: 467px;
}

.product__list_column--img {
  width: 500px;
  height: 872px;
  margin-top: -200px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.product__list-subtitle::before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 30px;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #342F3F;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.product__list-title {
  margin: 0 0 0 -5px;
  max-width: 598px;
}

.product__list_item {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  opacity: .4 !important;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.product__list_item_text_progress {
  height: 2px;
  max-width: 570px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #484848;
}

.product__list_item_text_progress_grad {
  background: #FAD4E7;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 99;
  width: 0%;
}

.product__list_item_text_progress_grad_one {
  animation: product_progress ease-out 25s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.product__list_item_text_progress_grad_two {
  animation: product_progress ease-out 25s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-delay: 5s;
}

.product__list_item_text_progress_grad_three {
  animation: product_progress ease-out 25s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-delay: 10s;
}

.product__list_item_text_progress_grad_four {
  animation: product_progress ease-out 25s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-delay: 15s;
}

.product__list_item_text_progress_grad_five {
  animation: product_progress ease-out 25s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-delay: 20s;
}

@keyframes product_progress {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  20% {
    width: 100%;
  }
  20.00000001% {
    width: 0%;
  }
  100% {
    width: 0%;
  }
}

@keyframes product_progress_one {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

.product-img {
  display:none;
  transition: 1s;
}
.active.product-img {
  display:block;
  transition: 1s;
}

.active.product__list_item {
  opacity: 1 !important;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.8s linear;
  transition: opacity 0.8s linear;
  color: #FAD4E7;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.active.product__list_item>div>.product__list_item-number{
  color: #FAD4E7;
  transition: 0.5s;

}

.product__list_item-num {
  line-height: 7px;
  width: 85px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.product__list_item-number {
  margin-top: -46px;
}

.product__list_item-num img {
  max-width: initial;
}

.product__list_item-text {
  max-width: 475px;
}
```

```html
<section class="product__list padding_top_130 padding_bottom_150 padding_top_78_1440">
        <div class="container container_two">
            <div class="product__list_wrapper">
                <div class="product__list_column product__list_column-1">
                    <p class="product__list-subtitle padding_bottom_10 p2_black">мы работаем с вами, а не для вас</p>
                    <h2 class="product__list-title padding_title_60 h2_black">Направления работы</h2>
                    <div class="product__list_item item-num-1 _anim-items padding_bottom_40 active product__list_item_one">
                        <div class="product__list_item-num product__list_item_one">
                            <p class="p7 product__list_item-number product__list_item_one">01.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="product__list_item-text product__list_item_one">
                            <p class="h3_black_300 padding_bottom_20 width_103 width_480_768 product__list_item_one">Создание сайтов</p>
                            <p class="p3_black padding_bottom_20 width_103 product__list_item_one">Разработка удобных для посетителя, элегантных и доступных для поиска сайтов, их сопровождение — это то, что вы получите при работе с нами.</p>
                            <!-- <progress class="progress" value="0" max="100">
                                <span class="percent">0</span>%
                            </progress> -->
                            <div class='product__list_item_text_progress product__list_item_one'><div class='product__list_item_text_progress_grad product__list_item_text_progress_grad_one product__list_item_one'></div></div>
                        </div>                   
                    </div>
                    <div class="product__list_item item-num-2 _anim-items padding_bottom_40 product__list_item_two">
                        <div class="product__list_item-num product__list_item_two">
                            <p class="p7 product__list_item-number product__list_item_two">02.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="product__list_item-text product__list_item_two">
                            <p class="h3_black_300 padding_bottom_20 width_103 width_480_768 product__list_item_two">Cоздание и SEO-продвижение сайтов</p>
                            <p class="p3_black padding_bottom_20 width_103 product__list_item_two">Умеем планировать разумную маркетинговую компанию, которая соответствует вашему бюджету при этом достигает максимальной эффективности.</p>
                            <!-- <progress class="progress" value="0" max="100">
                                <span class="percent">0</span>%
                            </progress> -->
                            <div class='product__list_item_text_progress product__list_item_two'><div class='product__list_item_text_progress_grad product__list_item_text_progress_grad_two product__list_item_two'></div></div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div  class="product__list_item item-num-3 _anim-items padding_bottom_40 product__list_item_three">
                        <div class="product__list_item-num product__list_item_three">
                            <p class="p7 product__list_item-number product__list_item_three">03.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="product__list_item-text product__list_item_three">
                            <p class="h3_black_300 padding_bottom_20 width_103 width_480_768 product__list_item_three">SMM-маркетинг</p>
                            <p class="p3_black padding_bottom_20 width_103 product__list_item_three">Быстрый способ привлечения це левых посетителей на сайт. Заказывая контекстную рекламу у нас, вы платите за результат – лояльных посетителей.</p>
                            <!-- <progress class="progress" value="0" max="100">
                                <span class="percent">0</span>%
                            </progress> -->
                            <div class='product__list_item_text_progress product__list_item_three'><div class='product__list_item_text_progress_grad product__list_item_text_progress_grad_three product__list_item_three'></div></div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="product__list_item item-num-4 _anim-items padding_bottom_40 product__list_item_four">
                        <div class="product__list_item-num product__list_item_four">
                            <p class="p7 product__list_item-number product__list_item_four">04.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="product__list_item-text margin_10_1440 product__list_item_four">
                            <p class="h3_black_300 padding_bottom_20 width_103 width_480_768 product__list_item_four">Контекстная и таргетированная реклама</p>
                            <p class="p3_black padding_bottom_20 width_103 width_103_500 product__list_item_four">Контекстная реклама нацелена на максимальное привлечение клиентов к вашему бизнесу или продукту. Она привлекает лояльных потребителей.</p>
                            <!-- <progress class="progress" value="0" max="100">
                                <span class="percent">0</span>%
                            </progress> -->
                            <div class='product__list_item_text_progress product__list_item_four'><div class='product__list_item_text_progress_grad product__list_item_text_progress_grad_four product__list_item_four'></div></div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="product__list_item item-num-5 _anim-items padding_bottom_40 product__list_item_five">
                        <div class="product__list_item-num product__list_item_five">
                            <p class="p7 product__list_item-number product__list_item_five">05.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="product__list_item-text product__list_item_five">
                            <p class="h3_black_300 padding_bottom_20 width_103 width_480_768 product__list_item_five">Дизайн</p>
                            <p class="p3_black padding_bottom_20 width_103 product__list_item_five">Предлагаем широкий спектр услуг, от web-дизайна до графического дизайна каталогов и брошюр, которые помогут вам создать корпоративный имидж.</p>
                            <!-- <progress class="progress" value="0" max="100">
                                <span class="percent">0</span>%
                            </progress> -->
                            <div class='product__list_item_text_progress product__list_item_five'><div class='product__list_item_text_progress_grad product__list_item_text_progress_grad_five product__list_item_five'></div></div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="product__list_column-2">
                    <div class="product__list_column--img margin_bottom_40">
                        <img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/img/jpg/img-hover1.jpg" alt="img" class="product-img product-img_1 active">
                        <img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/img/jpg/img-hover2.jpg" alt="img" class="product-img product-img_2">
                        <img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/img/jpg/img-hover3.jpg" alt="img" class="product-img product-img_3">
                        <img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/img/jpg/img-hover4.jpg" alt="img" class="product-img product-img_4">
                        <img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/img/jpg/img-hover5.jpg" alt="img" class="product-img product-img_5">
                    </div>
                        <div class="product__list_wrapper list_wrapper-hidden">
                            <div class="grad-line"></div>
                            <div class="product__list_column-text-2">
                                <p class="h3_black_300 padding_bottom_20">Мы работаем с вами, а не для вас!</p>                       
                                <p class="col-text-2 padding_bottom_10 p3_black padding_18_1440">Агентство интернет-рекламы полного цикла – так можно охарактеризовать работу нашей компании. Действительно, в реалиях 20-х годов нового тысячелетия об успехе онлайн можно говорить только при условии, что рычаги влияния применяются комплексно и системно. Как раз поэтому предполагается многовекторная работа
                                </p>
                                <p class="col-text-2 padding_bottom_10 p3_black padding_30_1440">Агентство интернет-маркетинга «Веб Фокус» – это воплощение проекта в жизнь с четким пониманием особенностей того или иного бизнеса. Считаем этот момент ключевым, ведь без учета сезонности, среднего чека и других нюансов раскрутка превращается в сумбурный набор движений, от которых толку немного.
                                </p>
                                <p class="col-text-2 padding_bottom_10 p3_black">Только точечные удары по аудитории, которые заставляют офисный телефон буквально разрываться от звонков! О Вас не знают? Исправим! Хотите увеличить продажи или улучшить репутацию? Будет сделано! Больше, чем среднестатистическое агентство разработки сайтов! 
                                </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="product__list_wrapper-hidden gradient">
                <div class="grad_line-text--wrapper">
                    <div class="product__list_wrapper-text">                    
                        <div class="grad-line"></div>
                        <div class="product__list_column-text-2">  
                            <p class="h3_black_300 padding_bottom_20 padding_bottom_21_500">Мы работаем с вами, а не для вас!</p>                      
                            <p class="col-text-2 col-text-2--p padding_bottom_10 p3_black">Агентство интернет-рекламы полного цикла – так можно охарактеризовать работу нашей компании. Действительно, в реалиях 20-х годов нового тысячелетия об успехе онлайн можно говорить только при условии, что рычаги влияния применяются комплексно и системно. Как раз поэтому предполагается многовекторная работа</p>
                            <p class="col-text-2 padding_bottom_10 p3_black">Агентство интернет-маркетинга «Веб Фокус» – это воплощение проекта в жизнь с четким пониманием особенностей того или иного бизнеса. Считаем этот момент ключевым, ведь без учета сезонности, среднего чека и других нюансов раскрутка превращается в сумбурный набор движений, от которых толку немного.</p>
                            <p class="col-text-2 padding_bottom_10 p3_black">Только точечные удары по аудитории, которые заставляют офисный телефон буквально разрываться от звонков! О Вас не знают? Исправим! Хотите увеличить продажи или улучшить репутацию? Будет сделано! Больше, чем среднестатистическое агентство разработки сайтов! </p>
                   
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: а можете html добавить? будет более наглядно

Comment: Добавил, но там очень много разных классов, не думаю что будет понятно:(

Comment: Жесть, а можно в 2-х словах, что должна делать функция?

Comment: @Павел но теперь можно посмотреть, о чем идет речь

Comment: Заходим на сайт, долистываем до блока и: 1) запускается анимация (первый пункт опасити 1(т.е активный)) шкала внизу блока зполняется другим цветом, когда она полностью заполняется,  первый блок становится опасити 0.5, шкала становится черная. Второй блок становится опасити 1, меняется картинка и теперь у него идет шкала и т.д. 2) При наведении мышкой на блок, вся эта анимация прекращается и опасити 1 становится тот блок, на который мы наводим и у него тоже заполняется шкала, но после заполнения ничего не происходит. 3) Когда мы убираем мышь с блока, снова должен запуститься пункт "1)"

Comment: Интересная задача, не лучше ли вам с ней обратится на фриланс?

Comment: Да дело в том, что я сделал почти все, только не могу сделать так, чтобы функция останавливалась при наводе, а когда мышь убираю, заново запускалась

Comment: @Павел а можете убрать всё лишнее, которое не относится к решаемой задаче?

Comment: До этого так и было, но меня попросили HTML, а без доп CSS этот HTML был бесполезен, но я скорее всего решил эту проблему и скоро напишу ответ, когда проверю все ли правильно работает

Comment: @Павел если не решите, то  вместо 100500 классов и ненужного текста оставьте только нужные блоки с полоской.

Comment: Спасибо вам за стремление помочь, но я все же смог разобраться и выполнить эту задачу:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все оказалось куда проще. При наведении на блок, я очищал все setTimeout, а так же проверял сработали ли уже setTimeout, и если да, то значит были созданы уже setInterval, а значит очищал их тоже. А когда мышь убирал с блока, то снова запускал эту функцию

Да, код кривой, его можно оптимизировать, но в данный момент мне нужен был просто рабочий код, а писать сразу красиво я еще не умею:(

Вот код который получился:

```js
const imgHover = () => {
    const productImg = document.querySelectorAll('.product-img');
    const productImg1 = document.querySelector('.product-img_1');
    const productImg2 = document.querySelector('.product-img_2');
    const productImg3 = document.querySelector('.product-img_3');
    const productImg4 = document.querySelector('.product-img_4');
    const productImg5 = document.querySelector('.product-img_5');
    const itemNum = document.querySelectorAll('.product__list_item');
    const productListItemTextProgressGrad = document.querySelectorAll('.product__list_item_text_progress_grad');
    const productListItemTextProgressGradOne = document.querySelector('.product__list_item_text_progress_grad_one');
    const productListItemTextProgressGradTwo = document.querySelector('.product__list_item_text_progress_grad_two');
    const productListItemTextProgressGradThree = document.querySelector('.product__list_item_text_progress_grad_three');
    const productListItemTextProgressGradFour = document.querySelector('.product__list_item_text_progress_grad_four');
    const productListItemTextProgressGradFive = document.querySelector('.product__list_item_text_progress_grad_five');
    const itemNum1 = document.querySelector('.item-num-1');
    const itemNum2 = document.querySelector('.item-num-2');
    const itemNum3 = document.querySelector('.item-num-3');
    const itemNum4 = document.querySelector('.item-num-4');
    const itemNum5 = document.querySelector('.item-num-5');

    function prov(one, two, three, four) {
        productListItemTextProgressGrad.forEach(item => {
            item.style.animation = 'none';
        });
        itemNum.forEach(item => {
            item.classList.remove('active')
        });
        productImg.forEach(item => {
            item.classList.remove('active')
        });
        four.style.animation = "product_progress_one ease-out 5s forwards";
        itemNum.forEach(item => {
            item.classList.remove('active');
        })
        productImg.forEach(el => {
            el.classList.remove('active');
        })
        two.classList.add('active');
        three.classList.add('active');
    }



    const framesImg = () => {
        timerOne = setTimeout(() => {
            productListItemTextProgressGradOne.style.animation = 'product_progress linear 25s infinite'
            itemNum5.classList.remove('active');
            itemNum1.classList.add('active');
            productImg5.classList.remove('active');
            productImg1.classList.add('active');
            itemNum1.classList.add('one');
            intervalOne = setInterval(() => {
                productListItemTextProgressGradOne.style.animation = 'product_progress linear 25s infinite'
                itemNum5.classList.remove('active');
                itemNum1.classList.add('active');
                productImg5.classList.remove('active');
                productImg1.classList.add('active');
            }, 25000);
        }, 0);
        timerTwo = setTimeout(() => {
            productListItemTextProgressGradTwo.style.animation = 'product_progress linear 25s infinite'
            itemNum1.classList.remove('active');
            itemNum2.classList.add('active');
            productImg1.classList.remove('active');
            productImg2.classList.add('active');
            itemNum2.classList.add('two');
            intervalTwo = setInterval(() => {
                productListItemTextProgressGradTwo.style.animation = 'product_progress linear 25s infinite'
                itemNum1.classList.remove('active');
                itemNum2.classList.add('active');
                productImg1.classList.remove('active');
                productImg2.classList.add('active');
            }, 25000);
        }, 5000);
        timerThree = setTimeout(() => {
            productListItemTextProgressGradThree.style.animation = 'product_progress linear 25s infinite'
            itemNum2.classList.remove('active');
            itemNum3.classList.add('active');
            productImg2.classList.remove('active');
            productImg3.classList.add('active');
            itemNum3.classList.add('three');
            intervalThree = setInterval(() => {
                itemNum3.classList.add('three');
                productListItemTextProgressGradThree.style.animation = 'product_progress linear 25s infinite'
                itemNum2.classList.remove('active');
                itemNum3.classList.add('active');
                productImg2.classList.remove('active');
                productImg3.classList.add('active');
            }, 25000);
        }, 10000);
        timerFour = setTimeout(() => {
            productListItemTextProgressGradFour.style.animation = 'product_progress linear 25s infinite'
            itemNum3.classList.remove('active');
            itemNum4.classList.add('active');
            productImg3.classList.remove('active');
            productImg4.classList.add('active');
            itemNum4.classList.add('four');
            intervalFour = setInterval(() => {
                itemNum4.classList.add('four');
                productListItemTextProgressGradFour.style.animation = 'product_progress linear 25s infinite'
                itemNum3.classList.remove('active');
                itemNum4.classList.add('active');
                productImg3.classList.remove('active');
                productImg4.classList.add('active');
            }, 25000);
        }, 15000);
        timerFive = setTimeout(() => {
            productListItemTextProgressGradFive.style.animation = 'product_progress linear 25s infinite'
            itemNum4.classList.remove('active');
            itemNum5.classList.add('active');
            productImg4.classList.remove('active');
            productImg5.classList.add('active');
            itemNum5.classList.add('five');
            intervalFive = setInterval(() => {
                itemNum5.classList.add('five');
                productListItemTextProgressGradFive.style.animation = 'product_progress linear 25s infinite'
                itemNum4.classList.remove('active');
                itemNum5.classList.add('active');
                productImg4.classList.remove('active');
                productImg5.classList.add('active');
            }, 25000);
        }, 20000);
    }

    framesImg();


    itemNum.forEach(elem => {
        elem.addEventListener('mouseover', (e) => {
            if (itemNum1.classList.contains('one')) {
                clearInterval(intervalOne);
            }
            if (itemNum2.classList.contains('two')) {
                clearInterval(intervalTwo);
            }
            if (itemNum3.classList.contains('three')) {
                clearInterval(intervalThree);
            }
            if (itemNum4.classList.contains('four')) {
                clearInterval(intervalFour);
            }
            if (itemNum5.classList.contains('five')) {
                clearInterval(intervalFive);
            }
            clearTimeout(timerOne);
            clearTimeout(timerTwo);
            clearTimeout(timerThree);
            clearTimeout(timerFour);
            clearTimeout(timerFive);
            if(e.target.classList.contains('product__list_item_one')) {
                prov(0, productImg1, itemNum1, productListItemTextProgressGradOne);
            } else if (e.target.classList.contains('product__list_item_two')) {
                prov(1, productImg2, itemNum2, productListItemTextProgressGradTwo);
            } else if (e.target.classList.contains('product__list_item_three')) {
                prov(2, productImg3, itemNum3, productListItemTextProgressGradThree);
            } else if (e.target.classList.contains('product__list_item_four')) {
                prov(3, productImg4, itemNum4, productListItemTextProgressGradFour);
            } else if (e.target.classList.contains('product__list_item_five')) {
                prov(4, productImg5, itemNum5, productListItemTextProgressGradFive);
            } 
        });
        elem.addEventListener('mouseout', (e) => {
            productListItemTextProgressGrad.forEach(item => {
                item.style.animation = 'none';
            });
            itemNum.forEach(item => {
                item.classList.remove('active')
            });
            productImg.forEach(item => {
                item.classList.remove('active')
            });
            framesImg();
        });
    });
}

const productList = document.querySelector('.product__list');
let box = productList.getBoundingClientRect();
let isRun = false;
window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {

    if (window.pageYOffset >= box.top - document.documentElement.clientHeight + 250 && !isRun) {
        imgHover()
        isRun = true;      
    } 
});
```

Comment: Вы ничего не поняли.

Comment: Ну почему же? У меня все до этого работало, но только я не мог остановить функцию, так как там был seTimeout, и снова запускать её. У меня сразу много функций запускалось, а сейчас все работает. Да, код может кривой, но он же работает. А писать качественный код придёт со временем. И если вы говорите что ничего не понял, то почему не подсказали хотя бы нужное направление?

Comment: Что-то прям на код супер больно смотреть, местами даже читать нет желания. Однако я сам не знаю как сходу решить эту задачу и возможно что-то похожее можно ожидать от первого решения, а вот потом уже думать над оптимизацией. Ну тут как минимум вы получаете каждый элемент за место коллекции. Короче если проще , нету какой-то автоматизации и очень много нарушений Don’t repeat yourself

Answer (score 0):

```
Пока мне удалось сделать это - я работаю над улучшением
```

[Cсылка на stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-yvk7ze?file=script.js)